# How to supply objects to styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

How can you supply objects to styled components for simplicity. This way, I have access to the theme for all my properties, importantly do not have to use `-` and can supply ints rather than everything being a string.

```
const Div = styled.div(() => ({
  padding: 20,
  border: '1px solid #c6d4df',
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
}))
```

### Rrror

```
TypeScript error in /var/www/property-estimating/frontend/claim-handler/src/components/Overview/index.tsx(13,35):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray): StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
      Type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TemplateStringsArray': raw, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, any>>'.
      Type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; }, any>>'.
        Type '{ padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; }, any>>'.
          Type '{ padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.
            Types of property 'boxSizing' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BoxSizing | undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & object, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
      Type '() => { padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
        Type '{ padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
          Type '{ padding: number; border: string; boxSizing: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.  TS2769

    11 | }
    12 | 
  > 13 | const OverviewStyled = styled.div(() => ({
       |                                   ^
    14 |   padding: 20,
    15 |   border: '1px solid #c6d4df',
    16 |   boxSizing: 'border-box'
```

Comment: Not really related, I'm just curious about why React devs try to style things this way? What the heck is wrong with using normal CSS? I just think it's funny how the development community spent years convincing people to separate things, and then React comes around and does the exact opposite ‍♂️

Comment: Man, I've just a 30mins conversation with another JS dev who loves styled-components and I'm of the view I would must prefer to use `css`.... give me object notation and themes so I can share styles easily, or let me just `css` please!! Not a fan of CS lol

Comment: `styled-components` can be a pain. I prefer a configurable set of utility classes like `Bootstrap` or `TailwindCSS`. Still, the beauty of `CSS-in-JS` solutions are modularization. You only load the CSS you need when you need it. Still, something like css-modules are great for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styled-components` use Tagged Template Literals to configure a component, see: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#tagged-template-literals

But, the first argument for a styled-component can either be a interpolated template string, a string array, or a `CSSObject`. See this post for the latter, which will apply in your case: https://paulie.dev/posts/2020/08/styled-components-style-objects/

You should be able to do:

```js
const Div = styled.div({
  padding: 20,
  border: '1px solid #c6d4df',
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
})
```

See CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-morning-yx6ht